# How can I change the default styling for Jquery require_from_group method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validation plugin to produce an alert that pops up if the user does not check at least one box in a group for a form, utilizing the **require_from_group** Method.  However, there is a lot of checkboxes and it looks quite odd when an alert appears in the middle of all thirty checkbox options.  I would like for just one alert to appear at the top of the group.  How can this be done?

This is a picture of what I'm talking about:

[thirty-four alerts when all I want is one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgIh8.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Occupation: Check All That Apply</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="checkbox">

      <label>
        <input class="occupation-group" onchange="showHideControlgrowerchecks();" type="checkbox" name="Grower" id="Grower"> Grower</label>
      <br>

      <label>
        <input class="occupation-group" type="checkbox" name="PCA_Consultant" id="PCA_Consultant"> PCA/Consultant</label>
      <br>

      <label>
        <input class="occupation-group" type="checkbox" name="Packer_Processor" id="Packer_Processor"> Packer/Processor</label>
      <br>

      <label>
        <input class="occupation-group" type="checkbox" name="Research_Gov_Ed" id="Research_Gov_Ed"> Research/Gov/Ed</label>
      <br>

      <label>
        <input class="occupation-group" type="checkbox" name="Assn_Commission" id="Assn_Commission"> Assn/Commission</label>
      <br>

      <label>
        <input class="occupation-group" type="checkbox" name="Suppliermfgsvc" id="Suppliermfgsvc"> Supplier/Mfg/Svc</label>
      <br>

      <label>
        <input class="occupation-group" type="checkbox" name="Ad_Agency" id="Ad_Agency"> Ad Agency</label>
      <br>

      <label>
        <input class="occupation-group" type="checkbox" onchange="showHideControloccupation();" name="Other" id="Other"> Other</label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" style="display:none" name="Occupation-Other" id="Occupation-Other" placeholder="Please Specify Other Occupation Here" required>
      <br>
      <br>



    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#form1").validate({
  rules: {
    Grower: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".occupation-group"]
    },
    PCA_Consultant: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".occupation-group"]
    },
    Packer_Processor: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".occupation-group"]
    },
    Research_Gov_Ed: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".occupation-group"]
    },
    Assn_Commission: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".occupation-group"]
    },
    Suppliermfgsvc: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".occupation-group"]
    },
    Ad_Agency: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".occupation-group"]
    },
    Other: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".occupation-group"]
    }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as *"default styling"* for the `require_from_group` method.

To combine the 34 messages into one, use [the `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups).

If you don't like where the plugin is putting the validation message, use [the `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to change it.  Within your custom function, you could use a conditional to move the message for one type of thing, leaving the default placement for everything else.